# Automation error when opening Edge using SeleniumBasic in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-edgedriver

Edge won't open.

Similar issue as [reported by vasilythecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471702/vba-class-not-registered-seleniumbasic-using-edgedriver-to-open-webpage) but I get an automation error message at: `obj.Start "edge", ""`

[image: Automation error message]

These are the steps I took.

I downloaded and installed Selenium Basic from https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0 .

I downloaded the Microsoft Edge WebDriver (Stable Channel) that corresponds to the version of Edge on my machine. I copied the Edge WebDriver, msedgedriver.exe, into the directory where Selenium Basic is installed and renamed it edgedriver.exe.

I created a module in a blank Excel file and added the following code. I removed comments, if you are comparing this to the screen shot.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub automation()
    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "edge", ""
End Sub
```

I am using Office 2019 (32-bit), Edge v99.0.1150.39 (64-bit). I also configured Excel to enable all macros.

[This site](https://simpleexcelvba.com/google-chrome-automation-with-selenium-basic/) mentions that Selenium Basic required .NET framework 3.5 or higher.

According to [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), the version of .NET Framework may be determined from the registry. This registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full shows that I have 4.8.04084 installed.

I tried the x86 and x64 versions of the Microsoft Edge WebDriver and got the same results.

The error also comes up when I delete edgedriver.exe and deliberately do not rename msedgedriver.exe.

As far as I can tell, Selenium Basic is still supposed to work.

This is critical to get legacy IE automation to work.

Version of Edge on my machine
[image: Version of Edge on my machine]

Location of Selenium Basic installation (x86 version of Edge WebDriver used for edgedriver.exe)
[image: Location of Selenium Basic installation]

Version of Edge WebDriver
[image: Version of Edge WebDriver]

.NET Framework version
[image: .NET Framework version]

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention that I also added Selenium Type Library to the Excel References.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found [a post with an example that works](https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/install-selenium-to-use-chrome-with-excel-vba/).

The proper syntax to start the web browser is:
obj.Start "edge"

Also, .NET Framework 3.5 needs to be installed. The code does not work when only newer versions of .NET are installed.

[Instructions on how to install the .NET Framework](https://clearithere.wordpress.com/2020/03/20/solved-run-time-error-2146232576-80131700-automation-error-in-excel/)